# Why is my RecordCount 0 when it shouldn't be?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am trying to get the results from a query I made in an Access Database. However, when I query the database in excel, the query has no return values. Why is this? When I attempt to query (from excel) plain tables or other queries, values return as expected.

My Code:

```
Sub sqlCode()
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim StrDBPath As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryHeadsA_ExcelOutput"

    StrDBPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Daily Closing Report V997.accdb"

    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                             "Data Source=" & StrDBPath & ";" & _
                             "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" & _
                             "Persist Security Info=False;"

    rst.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

    CopyText (strSQL)

    MsgBox rst.RecordCount

    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```

SQL in Query:

```
SELECT [Heads A].[Date Entered], [Heads A Issues].Department, [Heads A Issues].Equipment, [Heads A Issues].[Operation Issues], Sum([Heads A Issues].Downtime) AS SumOfDowntime1, IIf([Head A Crew]='3','C-Crew',IIf([Head A Crew]='2','B-Crew','A-Crew')) AS Crew
FROM [Heads A] INNER JOIN [Heads A Issues] ON [Heads A].[HeadLineA ID] = [Heads A Issues].[HeadLineA ID]
GROUP BY [Heads A].[Date Entered], [Heads A Issues].Department, [Heads A Issues].Equipment, [Heads A Issues].[Operation Issues], IIf([Head A Crew]='3','C-Crew',IIf([Head A Crew]='2','B-Crew','A-Crew'))
HAVING ((([Heads A Issues].Department)='9240A-F') And ((IIf([Head A Crew]='3','C-Crew',IIf([Head A Crew]='2','B-Crew','A-Crew'))) Like IIf('ALL'='all','*-Crew','ALL')))
ORDER BY [Heads A Issues].Department, [Heads A Issues].Equipment;
```

Again, in the Access DB this query provides over 10k records that fit this criteria. Are there options in Access that would limit what my excel file can query?

Comment: if you copy the recordset to a range, does it still not show any results? `Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst`

Comment: @lturner No results are shown when I try to copy from recordset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause includes this condition ...

```sql
Like IIf('ALL'='all','*-Crew','ALL')
```

However, you're using the query from ADO, which requires a different wildcard character: `%` instead of `*`.  So you can change it to this for ADO ...

```sql
Like IIf('ALL'='all','%-Crew','ALL')
```

But that means you would need 2 versions of the same basic query: one for design and testing in Access; and another for use with ADO.  If you prefer one query which operates the same in both situations, use `ALike` with the `%` wild card instead of `Like` ...

```sql
ALike IIf('ALL'='all','%-Crew','ALL')
```

Although the query should then return the same results in both situations, I'm unsure about the logic of that `IIf` expression.  Since text comparisons in Access SQL are case-insensitive, `'ALL'='all'` will always be True ... which means the condition is equivalent to `ALike '%-Crew'`.  In other words, that expression will never give you a condition which is the equivalent of `ALike 'ALL'`

Comment: `'ALL'='all'` should be be actually comparing a value the user inputs, but I thought that it may have been the issue before. I just hadn't gotten around to changing it back. But this completely worked! You are a life saver, for real! I really appreciate it.